# Recode variable in R based on first characters of vector

Tags: r, recode

I have a data frame which looks like this:

```
codes <- c('TFAA1', 'TFAA2', 'TFAA3', 'TFAA4', 'TFAB1', 'TFAB2', 'TFAB3', 'TFAB4')
scores <- c(4,3,2,2,4,5,1,2)
example <- data.frame(codes, scores)
```

I want to create a new column called code_group whereby everything that starts with TFAA gets called "Group1" and everything that starts with TFAB gets called "Group2".

Have been playing with the recode function from the car package, and the grepl function but I'm failing miserably. Here's my attempt so far....

```
recode <- (codes, "%in% TFAA='Group1'; %in% TFAB='Group2'")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `dplyr` and `stringr` you can get it done:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
example %>% 
  mutate(code_group = case_when(str_detect(codes, "^TFAA") ~ "Group1",
                              str_detect(codes, "^TFAB") ~ "Group2"))
```

`case_when` lets you use multiple if-then cases. `str_detect` lets you, well, detect the pattern you seek in a string.

Comment: `startsWith` can substitute `str_detect` of course.

Answer (score 1):

```
example$code_group <- ifelse(startsWith(codes, 'TFAA'), 'Group 1', 
                      ifelse(startsWith(codes, 'TFAB'), 'Group 2',
                             NA))
```

Answer (score 1):

We could extract the first four characters with `substr`, convert it to `factor` and specify the `labels` as the one we wanted

```
example$code_group <-  with(example,  as.character(factor(substr(codes, 1, 4), 
              levels = c('TFAA', 'TFAB'), labels = c('Group1', 'Group2'))))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `split<-` :

```
example$group <- NA
split(example$group,substr(example$codes,1,4)) <- paste0("Group",1:2)
example
#   codes scores  group
# 1 TFAA1      4 Group1
# 2 TFAA2      3 Group1
# 3 TFAA3      2 Group1
# 4 TFAA4      2 Group1
# 5 TFAB1      4 Group2
# 6 TFAB2      5 Group2
# 7 TFAB3      1 Group2
# 8 TFAB4      2 Group2
```

Or we can use factors for the same output (3 variants):

```
example$group <- paste0("Group",factor(substr(example$codes,1,4),,1:2))
example$group <- paste0("Group",as.numeric(factor(substr(example$codes,1,4))))
example$group <- factor(substr(example$codes,1,4),,paste0("Group",1:2))
```

In the last case you get a factor column, in all other cases you get a character column.